# gridview link button are not work in other column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` and in it there are some columns:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <i class="icon-edit icon-white" style="position: absolute;
            margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 7px;"></i>
        <a href="#" id="Button1" class="btn btn-success"><p>Loan Calculation</p></a>
        <asp:Button ID="btnapp" runat="server" Text="Approved" CommandName="Approved"
            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("rcno")+ "," +Eval("mobile")+ "," +Eval("email") %>'
            class="btn btn-success" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image: View of the columns]

**This has successfully worked in only one column, not in the other column**

Comment: Do you get any error? Please give us more information about how it's not working.

Comment: Please add some more code. Cant see that anything is wrong with your anchor code you posted.

Comment: main problem is in first column it work only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Hyperlink` to link the column in `GridView`.

Kindly check below example:

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="Hyperlink2" CssClass="control" runat="Server"
    NavigateUrl='<%#Bind("link")%>' Text='<%#Bind("Title")%>'>
</asp:Hyperlink>
```